# Opposite SQL Query for Prestashop Database | Show products not in warehouse

Tags: mysql, sql, select, prestashop

I need help for an SQL query. Basically, i'm looking for products not in warehouse, in a Prestashop database (an e-commerce cms, fyi). I have this list of products in the table ps_product_lang, where i can also see the name of the products, and i'm joining the products' IDs into that to recover informations from 2 other tables that handle the warehouses ( ps_warehouse_product_location and ps_warehouse ). I made the query to show me in which warehouse are the products, that is this one:

```
SELECT A.id_product AS IdProd, A.name AS Nome, B.id_warehouse AS IdMag, C.name AS Magazzino FROM ps_product_lang A
INNER JOIN ps_warehouse_product_location B ON A.id_product = B.id_product
INNER JOIN ps_warehouse C on B.id_warehouse = C.id_warehouse
WHERE 1
```

Now, of course, i need just the opposite. Keep in mind the products' IDs are in the ps_product_lang table. How can i do that?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.id_product AS IdProd, A.name AS Nome, B.id_warehouse AS IdMag, C.name AS Magazzino FROM ps_product_lang A
LEFT JOIN ps_warehouse_product_location B ON A.id_product = B.id_product
LEFT JOIN ps_warehouse C on B.id_warehouse = C.id_warehouse
WHERE C.id_warehouse IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. PS's Back Office Sql Manager just says it doesn't show results. From PHPMyAdmin the same, it just generates void result.
edit: i forgot to say that id_warehouse field is not present in the ps_product_lang table

Comment: @NandoPC Please see edit, does it help if you change the other `inner join` to `left join`?

Comment: Looks like it's working now, that's perfect, thank you :) I also added another variable to control only activated products, so i will narrow down them. This way: http://pastebin.com/W3FYv8Cf 
Can you explan me the details behind left join and inner join difference? I'm a beginner in sql and i want to learn better these aspects :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: @NandoPC Google is your friend, there are many, many good tutorials about joins. I think even the Wikipedia page gives enough information.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could simply use `NOT IN` with a subquery:

```
SELECT id_product
FROM ps_product_lang
WHERE id_product NOT IN (
    SELECT p.id_product
    FROM ps_product_lang p
    INNER JOIN ps_warehouse_product_location wpl
        ON p.id_product = wpl.id_product
)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I solved with @HoneyBadger advice, expanding it after and now it's working as expected :) I will also try your solution for test purpose :) Thanks again.